# The word complimentary

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

Will it be better if we use the word mutual instead of complimentary in this following sentence ?

> The relationship between phototrophs and chemotrophs is **complimetary** (sic):
>   chemotrophs require oxygen and expire carbon dioxide while phototrophs
>   require carbon dioxide and expire oxygen.

Comment: Where did you get this from? You should cite quoted material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship between chemotrophs and phototrophs, as described, can be regarded as both mutual and complementary.

Mutual means that this relationship is beneficial for both, whereas to *complement* each other (it should be **complementary**, not complimentary) means that the two complete each other.

Comment: Good answer, but needs better punctuation for clarity. May I edit?